# Curl does not write to cookies.txt?

Tags: php, curl, cookies, authentication

I am trying to write a Cookie after login to cookies.txt.

My source code:

`$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    'loginMail='.$username.'&password='.$password.'&targetUrl=');
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt'); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt'); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $store = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);`

The output of the store variable shows that login was successful. But there is no change in the cookies.txt. Rights are set to 777. After login there is a redirect on the page.

What might be the reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the code from your apache, the use the full path for the cookie file instead of the `cookies.txt`. For example

```
/var/some-dir/tmp/cookies.txt
```